I cannot get this Text-Based game to work for the life of me: new to coding
I am taking a coding class and doing the ever so famous text based game, I have tried various ways to try and get this game to work and no variation will work
When it comes to entering the command to change rooms; it says invalid commands.
So i cannot test anything further until I am able to get that far. I had it working and then I added a more complex dictionary and everything went to poop.
I dont know if i need to go back down to simpler dictionaries with easier identifyers or if i can simply find a way to make this work.
this is the full code:
areas_dic = {
    'Home': {'name': 'Home', 'go East': 'Plains', 'item': 'none'},
    'Plains': {'name': 'Plains', 'go North': 'Rocky Terrain', 'go East': 'Fields', 'go South':   'Stream', 'item': 'Grains'},
    'Stream': {'name': 'Stream', 'go East': 'Forest', 'item': 'Water'},
    'Forest': {'name': 'Forest', 'go West': 'Stream', 'item': 'Firewood'},
    'Fields': {'name': 'Fields', 'go West': 'Plains', 'go North': 'Farmlands', 'item': 'Vegetables'},
    'Rocky Terrain': {'name': 'Rocky Terrain', 'go South': 'Plains', 'go East': 'up the Mountain',   'item': 'Medicinal Flowers'},
    'up the Mountain': {'name': 'up the Mountain', 'go West': 'Rocky Terrain', 'go East': 'Mountain Top', 'item': 'Warmer Clothes'},
    'Farmlands': {'name': 'Farmlands', 'go South': 'Fields', 'go West': 'DYSENTERY', 'item': 'Jerky'},
    'Mountain Top': {'name': 'Mountain Top', 'go West': 'up the Mountain', 'go South': 'DYSENTERY',   'item': 'Milk'}
    }

    print('Welcome to Old Americas')
    print('Object of the game is to collect all 7 items before falling ill')
    print('You can type go North, go South, go East, go West to move')


    current_location = 'Home'
    inventory = \[\]


    required_items = {'Grains', 'Water', 'Firewood', 'Vegetables', 'Medicinal Flowers', 'Warmer Clothes', 'Milk'}


    while True:
    print(f"You are in the {areas_dic\[current_location\]\['name'\]}.")

        # Display available directions
        directions = [direction for direction in areas_dic[current_location] if direction.startswith('go ')]
        print("Available directions:", ", ".join(directions))
    
        # Get player input
        command = input("Enter your command): ").strip().lower()
    
        # Process player input
   
    >  if command in directions:
    > direction = command.split()[1]
    > if direction in areas_dic[current_location]:
    > current_location = areas_dic[current_location][direction]
                item = areas_dic[current_location].get('item', None)
                if item:
                    print(f"You found {item}!")
                    inventory.append(item)
                    if item in required_items:
                        required_items.remove(item)
                        print(f"Items left to collect: {', '.join(required_items)}")
            else:
                print("You can't go that way!")
        else:
            print("Invalid command. Try again.")
        
        # Check if player has collected all items
        if not required_items:
            print("Congratulations! You've collected all items. Now face the villain in DYSENTERY!")
            break
        
        # Check if player has reached the final room
        if current_location == 'DYSENTERY':
            if 'illness' in inventory:
                print("You have fallen ill. Game over!")
            else:
                print("You defeated the illness and survived the journey! Well done!")
            break


the block quote is where i am having the problems. or i think i am, i dont know if i am not formatting it correctly or if it needs something all together different.

Your input statement uses lower(), so the input will be in lowercase, such as "go east".  But the directions in your areas dictionary are capitalized, such as "go East".  So they do not match.

As John Gordon said in a comment, the .lower() seems to be what is messing up the code. Luckily, this should be a really easy fix.
Here is what I did to fix your problem:
#...
command = input("Enter your command): ").strip().lower()

# Checks each given direction
for direction in directions:

    # using .lower here means that no matter how we type go x it will always work.
    if command in direction.lower():
        # direction = command.split()[1]
        # ...
        
        if item:
            print(f"You found {item}!")
            inventory.append(item)

            # ...

            # We add a 'break' every time we want it to stop at the other directions.
            # This isn't strictly neccessary, but it helps save some processing power, even if it
            # pretty much non-existant.
            break

        # ...

# This is added to the end so that if it goes through all of the directions
# and can't find one, it'll return the message "Invalid Command"
else:
    print("Invalid command. Try again.")

I didn't go through all the code, as in where every "break" would be placed, but hopefully you get the idea. Here's the explanation in words, instead of comments:
The for loop will check every direction. If it cant find any, it will go to the else statement at the end, and return the Invalid Command message. By adding .lower to direction and the command, we can make it so that  even if you type 'gO EaSt' or anything like that, it'll work. We can add break statements whenever we want the program to return to the "command =..." line.
This is what the full code should look like:
areas_dic = {
    'Home': {'name': 'Home', 'go East': 'Plains', 'item': 'none'},
    'Plains': {'name': 'Plains', 'go North': 'Rocky Terrain', 'go East': 'Fields', 'go South': 'Stream',
               'item': 'Grains'},
    'Stream': {'name': 'Stream', 'go East': 'Forest', 'item': 'Water'},
    'Forest': {'name': 'Forest', 'go West': 'Stream', 'item': 'Firewood'},
    'Fields': {'name': 'Fields', 'go West': 'Plains', 'go North': 'Farmlands', 'item': 'Vegetables'},
    'Rocky Terrain': {'name': 'Rocky Terrain', 'go South': 'Plains', 'go East': 'up the Mountain',
                      'item': 'Medicinal Flowers'},
    'up the Mountain': {'name': 'up the Mountain', 'go West': 'Rocky Terrain', 'go East': 'Mountain Top',
                        'item': 'Warmer Clothes'},
    'Farmlands': {'name': 'Farmlands', 'go South': 'Fields', 'go West': 'DYSENTERY', 'item': 'Jerky'},
    'Mountain Top': {'name': 'Mountain Top', 'go West': 'up the Mountain', 'go South': 'DYSENTERY', 'item': 'Milk'}
}

print('Welcome to Old Americas')
print('Object of the game is to collect all 7 items before falling ill')
print('You can type go North, go South, go East, go West to move')

current_location = 'Home'
inventory = []


required_items = {'Grains', 'Water', 'Firewood', 'Vegetables', 'Medicinal Flowers', 'Warmer Clothes', 'Milk'}

while True:
    print(f"\nYou are {current_location}.\n")

    # Display available directions
    directions = [direction for direction in areas_dic[current_location] if direction.startswith('go ')]
    print("Available directions:", ", ".join(directions))

    # Get player input
    command = input("Enter your command): ").strip().lower()


    # Process player input
    for direction in directions:
        if command in direction.lower():
            # direction = command.split()[1]
            if direction in areas_dic[current_location]:
                current_location = areas_dic[current_location][direction]

            item = areas_dic[current_location].get('item', None)

            if item:
                print(f"You found {item}!")
                inventory.append(item)
                if item in required_items:
                    required_items.remove(item)
                    print(f"Items left to collect: {', '.join(required_items)}")
                break
            else:
                print("You can't go that way!")
            # Check if player has collected all items
            if not required_items:
                print("Congratulations! You've collected all items. Now face the villain in DYSENTERY!")
                break

                # Check if player has reached the final room
            if current_location == 'DYSENTERY':
                if 'illness' in inventory:
                    print("You have fallen ill. Game over!")
                else:
                    print("You defeated the illness and survived the journey! Well done!")
                break
    else:
        print("Invalid command. Try again.")


I removed "direction = command.split()[1]" because that made it so that "if direction in areas_dic[current_location]:" would always be false.

I have done what you have suggested and i am still not able to move. I noticed that it said while true and 'home' as current area so im playing arround with that but now i cant get a starting area. I am very disapointed in this class ciriculum because i dont feel like i learned anything. I have learned more on this website decoding the code and using it in my own projects than what the textbook and class have given me.

@PretTyAndScaRy I see.. I did have to modify your code to some extent in order for it to work, but I wasn't sure if it was Stack Overflow or your code. For example, the "inventory = []" should be "inventory = []" I was able to play the game when I tested it out on my computer. I will edit my answer with the full code, and hopefully that will fix your issue. Take a look at both codes and see what changed.

If it is still unable to solve your problem, try using a different IDE. Like pycharm or something of the sort.

I am using pycharm :) it shows me whats wrong, i fix it and still i have errors. I think i am just going to start over again and hope for the best... this was due yesterday

If that's the case, the most probable thing I can think of is that your python version is too old. What errors is it giving you? Also, don't feel discouraged, this is good code! You have a lot of very good practices and the code is very clear.
